# Concatenating the values of one column into a single row

Tags: linq

I have the result of a database query for a single user as:

```
Name   |  Role
Tom    |  Admin
Tom    |  Manager
```

I want to convert the result into an object:

```
{ Name = "Tom", Roles = "Admin, Manager" }
```

I can do it using a `foreach` and too many statements. How can it be done using a LINQ query?

The sample code can be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = new [] { new { Name = "Tom", Role = "Admin"}, 
                              new { Name = "Tom", Role="Manager"}
                          };

        string roles = "";
        foreach (var u in result)
            roles += "," + u.Role;
        Console.WriteLine(result[0].Name + " " + roles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Linq.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) `Name` and select concatenating `Roles` by using [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join):

```
var groupedResult = result.GroupBy(g => g.Name)
                            .Select(s => new
                            {
                                Name = s.Key,
                                Roles = String.Join(",", s.Select(i => i.Role))
                            });
```

It will give you a list, if you want to get first item of list you can use:

```
var firstItem = groupedResult.FirstOrDefault();
```